# Add apple account to Visual Studio for Windows

Tags: windows, visual-studio, xamarin.ios

I am trying to add an Apple Account on VS 2017 running on Windows but it's giving me an error saying that it can't find a server with the specified hostname. I'm paired to a Mac mini.

[Screenshot of error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cEmQX.png)

Comment: Visual Studio 2019 for windows had released , so I suggest that you could update your IDE and check if the issue still exists .

Comment: Alright. I'll upgrade and get back to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I upgraded to VS 2K19 and my issue was solved. but I suspect that allowing Visual Studio to use public networks was the actual fix.